# elasticsearch mail Alerts via index Connector

Tags: elasticsearch, elastic-stack, elk

i am begginer in this so please can anyone help me out I want to get my apm service latency and error count to my mail via index connector.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [APM agents](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/apm/guide/current/apm-components.html) to collect the Application logs and metrics. After that, you can use the Kibana GUI [alert & rules](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/kibana/current/apm-alerts.html) to send emails according to some rules.

[image]

[image]